# Is there a way to annotate a function that takes an optional closure in rust?

Tags: rust, closures

I have a function that takes an optional closure and modifies a struct based on the return value.

For example:

```rust
fn main() {
  let mut s =  Struct::<usize> { inner: None };
  do_something(Some(|x:String|x.len()), &mut s);
  println!("{:?}",s);
  let mut s =  Struct::<usize> { inner: None };
  do_something(None, &mut s);

  println!("{:?}",s);
}

fn do_something<P, T: Fn(String) -> P>(fun: Option<T>, s: &mut Struct<P>) {
  *s = Struct {
      inner: fun.map(|fun| fun(String::from("abc")))
  };
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Struct<P> {
    inner: Option<P>
}
```

This should print:

```
Struct { inner: Some(3) }
Struct { inner: None }
```

But now it doesn't compile, since `cannot infer type for type parameter T declared on the function do_something`

Ok, let's try:

```
  let empty_function: Option<dyn Fn(String) -> usize> = None;
  do_something(empty_function, &mut s);
```

Also, doesn't work, since `empty_function` is unsized.

Is there a way annotate do_something so that this would work without `Box`?

Comment: Your empty function was *really close*: a trait object needs to be behind a pointer, which can be either a Box or a reference. So `Option<<&dyn Fn(_) -> _>`. `Option<Box<dyn Fn(_) -> _>>` would also have been fine because... you're never actually creating a box just telling Rust that's what this is for typechecking purposes, so it doesn't really matter how you type it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the type of `None` with `None::<T>` and you can use function pointers (`fn` rather than `dyn Fn`) as basic sized pointers:

```rust
do_something(None::<fn(String) -> usize>, &mut s);
```

Comment: Also Rust only needs the type of the callable itself, it can infer the rest just fine, so you could write `None::<fn(_) -> _>` if you're feeling lazy and don't fear the retribution of your colleagues.